# Is the Lead formula field a different size?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a formula field in each of the objects: Contact and Lead.

In each is a calculated number. 0-100 in increments of 10.

I have another field in Contact that pushes an image to the screen depending on the aforementioned number. It works like a treat.

I am copying the code to the Lead object and its is now 5800. In every other respect this operation is identical..

```
if( Data_Score__c= 0, IMAGE("/resource/nums/000.png", "0"),if( Data_Score__c= 10, IMAGE("/resource/nums/010.png", "10"),if( Data_Score__c= 20, IMAGE("/resource/nums/020.png", "20"),if( Data_Score__c= 30, IMAGE("/resource/nums/030.png", "30"),if( Data_Score__c= 40, IMAGE("/resource/nums/040.png", "40"),if( Data_Score__c= 50, IMAGE("/resource/nums/050.png", "50"),if( Data_Score__c= 60, IMAGE("/resource/nums/060.png", "60"),if( Data_Score__c= 70, IMAGE("/resource/nums/070.png", "70"),if( Data_Score__c= 80, IMAGE("/resource/nums/080.png", "80"),if( Data_Score__c= 90, IMAGE("/resource/nums/090.png", "90"),IMAGE("/resource/nums/100.png","100")))))))))))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is Data_Score__c, a formula?

Comment: Sorry - yes - data_score__c is the formula on each of Contact and Lead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your inputs match your file names, you can optimize your formula like this:

```
IMAGE("/resource/nums/"&RIGHT("00"&TEXT(Data_Score__c),3)&".png")
```

By using Data_Score__c only once, you'll drastically reduce the character count.

Comment: why are you not using `LPAD(TEXT(Data_Score__c),3,"0")` ?

Comment: @Oleksiy No particular reason. I honestly never use LPAD, so I just forgot about it. Both are functionally the same from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the number you're talking about here - 5800 - is the compile size for the formula. I assume, based on the behaviour you're describing, that Data_Score__c is a formula field as well.

The compile size is the size of the database query that’s compiled from your formula syntax and executed using your data at
runtime. The query can be much larger than the formula syntax that generates it, because it requests data from all the fields involved,
performs operations, and in many cases performs error checking on resulting values. There's a limit of 5000 characters for a formula's compile size.

When you use a formula field (Call this FormulaA) inside of another formula field (FormulaB), the compile size for FormulaB is going to include the compile size for FormulaA. And if you include FormulaA multiple times, then each time you include FormulaA you're including it's compile size. So if FormulaA compiles to 1800 characters, FormulaB is 1800*3 plus whatever additional formula compilation is needed. And then you're over the limit.

So, anything you can do to reduce the number of times that FormulaA is used in FormulaB, you'll reduce your compile size. (There's a whole tip sheet on this from Salesforce: [Tips for Reducing Formula Size](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf).)

In this case, you're using Data_Score__c nine or ten times, so you want to reduce that number. You can do this in a number of ways, but one way is to use a CASE function:

```
CASE(Data_Score__c,
  0, IMAGE("/resource/nums/000.png", "0"),
  10, IMAGE("/resource/nums/010.png", "10"),
  ...
  90, IMAGE("/resource/nums/090.png", "10"),
  IMAGE("/resource/nums/100.png","100")
)
```

Now you're using the Data_Score__c field once, which should reduce your formula field compile size below 1000.